# Lpsolve python installation error

Tags: python, lpsolve

When i download `lp_solve_5.5.2.0_Python_source.tar.gz`

and run `python setup.py install`

it throws:

```
pythonmod.h:15:20: fatal error: lp_lib.h: No such file or directory
 #include "lp_lib.h"
```

What do i need to do to install lpsolve.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install lp_solve first before installing the python adapter.

Comment: how do you do that? I copied like in the tutorial the so/pyd from lp_solve_5.5.2.0_Python2.5_exe_ux64.tar.gz to ~/local/python/site-packages

Comment: yes but the folder contains only a .so and a prebuild executeable "how exactly do you install something there"?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python 3.x look here: https://github.com/chandu-atina/lp_solve_python_3x